# How can I handle server-side errors globally in NextJS 13 with default React Error Boundary

Tags: error-handling, middleware, next.js13, react-error-boundary

I'm very new on NextJs and I'm just started to play around directly from the latest version.
I found it very interesting and enjoyable but i'm still confusing about some aspects the are clearer to me in other architectures.

At the moment I'm tryng to understand the default  Error boundary and how to leverage on it.

Sice I'm bulding a full stack application, I wondering how to handle errors globally.
I used to use something like Error middlewares in other frameworks but here it seems a little bit different.

I undersud from official docs that NextJs implement React Error Boundary and all pages are wrapped on it, upon adding special file error.js (as per naming convention)

All clear till now, you can handle client side error like a charm but what about server side?

Reading the docs in deep I found this:
***"If an error is thrown during data fetching or inside a Server Component, Next.js will forward the resulting Error object to the nearest error.js"***

So I start make some test but it seems it doesn't work  as I intended it.

Just an example:

Suppose you have a function Server side that retrieve some data from database.
That function is wrappen inside try-cacth in order to prevent unhandled exeptions.

Now when I come to client side and write something like that:

`const Home=()=>{ ... throw new Error('Error') ... return{} }`

its work properly and my custom error.js is renderend since it is wrapped inside React ErrorBoundary.

BUT

if OI try to do that:

```
`const Home=()=>{
     ...
     functionErrorTrigger(){
         throw new Error('Error')
     }

     ...
     return{
         <button onClick={ErrorTrigger}>ErrorTrigger<button>
     }
}`
```

It doesn't work, the error page is not displayed and the Exception is not graciously handled.

Here I'm trying to simulate for example an Error500 coming from my server.
Im ok with the fact that the App is not crashing but I need to notificate the end user if something is not working properly in order to avoid unusefull retries.

I'm trying to figured out what i'm missing here.. definitely something dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `error.js` into `not-found.js` and instead of throwing an error, add:

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';
```

To the top of your file and use:

```
functionErrorTrigger() {
  notFound()
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/not-found
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to take error props so you can't really notify the type of error, but if you just want a general "something went wrong" this is the only work around I've found.

Comment: thank you! that s a work around but better then nothing.. Other answers on top it would be the correct one but unfortunatly the global error doesn t fix.. I already tryed before.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `global-error.js` file. A special `error.js` file that works globally.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling#handling-errors-in-layouts